# How to know equation of this graph?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Coordinates are, 
On negative x-axis (-2,0)
On positive x-axis(2,0)
On negative y-axis (0,-6)
I know this is a parabola but how to know its equation?

Comment: How do you know it's a parabola?  Were you given that it was?

Comment: In the diagram it was given. @tilper

Comment: @mathematics $3$ points do not uniquely define a parabola, unless you have more information about it. Please edit the question and post *all* the assumptions of the problem.

Comment: @dxiv Yes they do (unless you're allowed to tilt the parabola, which in general does not give a function)

Comment: @dxiv : I suspect OP was told to find an equation of a (vertical) parabola passing through the specified points.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger `unless you're allowed to tilt the parabola` Precisely. The question as written doesn't say that the axis of symmetry must be vertical.

Comment: OP, was the parabola vertical, or could it have been tilted?

Comment: @MPW You need $4$ points in general, see for example [How Many Points Determine a Parabola?](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/53228.html).

Comment: @dxiv: Yes, I know that. But specifying a vertical parabola drops the degrees of freedom by one, so only three points are needed. But given the level of the question, I seriously doubt OP knows about rotating conic sections -- so that's why I said what I said in my comment above (note "vertical").

Comment: @MPW I agree, and the `graph` mentioned in the title but missing from the post could have well settled any doubt. Still wish the OP learned to post a complete question.

Comment: @dxiv : I suspect he is doing so even now ;)

Comment: It's symmetry is vertical @MPW

Comment: It's symmetry is vertical @dxiv

Comment: @mathematics The facts that (a) it's given that it's a parabola, and (b) known to have vertical symmetry are essential. Those belong into the question, not as comments.

Comment: @dxiv : Both of these would be assumed by most answering the question, I think

Comment: @MPW Sorry, but that is only reinforcing the idea in OP's mind that it's OK to ask ambiguous, incomplete questions, yet people will magically "know" what they really meant to ask. I don't think that's a healthy approach to math, but then that's just my opinion, so I guess we can agree to disagree and leave it at that.

Comment: Really zero personal input.

Answer (score 2):

You know that the roots are at $\pm 2$. Try to foil out $(x-2)(x+2)$ after that you need to multiply by an appropriate scaling factor.

Comment: The OP didn't specify that the axis of symmetry must be vertical. Without that assumption, there are infinitely many parabolas passing through those $3$ points.

Comment: @dxiv Yes, I assumed that. The OP also didn't say that he wanted the equation in Cartesian coordinates but as the question seems to be an Algebra 1 question some assumptions must be made.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** (I have assumed that the parabola as symmetry around a vertical line, which I think is a reasonable assumption). The general formula for a parabola is $y = ax^2+bx+c$. You get 3 equations with 3 variables from the 3 points:

Point $(x,y) = (-2,0)$:
$$0=a(-2)^2 + b(-2)+c $$

Point $(x,y) = (2,0)$:
$$0 = a(2)^2+b(2)+c $$
Point $(x,y) = (0,-6)$:
$$-6=a(0)^2+b(0) +c. $$

Another approach is that $y = \alpha(x-r_1)(x-r_2)$ where $r_1,r_2$ are roots. You have roots $r_1 =-2$ and $r_2 = 2$. Then you simply have to solve the equation for the last point $(x,y) = (0,-6)$
$$y = \alpha (x-r_1)(x-r_2).$$

Comment: It's symmetry is vertical @Eff

Answer (score 1):

By inspection, it's $$\frac{y}{6} = \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2 - 1$$
which can be rewritten as
$$y = \tfrac32 x^2 - 6$$

Answer (score 1):

A function whose graph is a parabola must be of the form $f(x)= ax^2+ bx+ c$.

You are told that f(-2)= 4a- 2b+ c= 0, that f(2)= 4a+ 2b+ c= 0, and that f(0)= c= -6.  So 4a- 2b- 6= 0 and 4a+ 2b- 6= 0.  Adding those two equations, 8a- 12= 0 so a= 12/8= 3/2.  Then 4(3/2)+ 2b- 6= 2b= 0 so b= 0.  The equation is of the form $f(x)= (3/2)x^2- 6= 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a *general* parabola, you have to know some results on `conics`.

The general equation of a conic is
$$Ax^2+2Bxy+Cy^2+2Dx+2Ey+F=0,$$
where the set of coefficients $(A,B,C,D,E,F)$ (not all $0$) is unique, up to a non-zero factor.

This conic is a parabola if and only if $B^2=AC$.

Let's write the equations in the set of coefficients resulting from the constraints:
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignedat}{3}
{}4&A&&+4D&+F=0 &\qquad&(1)\\
4&A&&-4D&+F=0&\qquad&(2)\\
36&C&&-12E&+F=0&\qquad&(3)
\end{alignedat}
\end{cases}
Eqs (1) and (2) imply $D=0$ and $F=-4A$. From eq. $3$, we deduce the relation
$$A=9C-3E.$$
Thus the conics passing through the three points have equation
$$C(9x^2+y^2-36)+2Bxy+E(-3x^2+2y+12)=0.$$
These conics are parabolas if and only if
$$B^2=AC=(9C-3E)C.$$

Note that we get the parabola defined by a quadratic function for $B=C=0$.